# Text to Columns with blank cells

Tags: excel, vba, multiple-columns, text-to-column

I saw the Post of J.Con about the text to column loop ([Text to columns for multiple columns - Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56746245/text-to-columns-for-multiple-columns-excel-vba)). However this only works if the first row has all the information, like in first picture:[image]

So I changed the code so it is working like in the second picture. This one works a sort of. Only I want that it works like in the third pictures that it finds the last column where the cell is not blank, so in this case cell("C3")
[image]
[image]

The code I use:

```
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=Range("A1"), _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        searchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Column

    Dim LastColumn As Long
    LastColumn = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=Range("A1"), _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        searchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Column


'Loops Text to columns
    Dim StartingRow, StartingColumn As Long
    StartingRow = 1

    For StartingColumn = 1 To LastColumn
        Range(Cells(StartingRow, StartingColumn), Cells(LastRow, StartingColumn)).Select

        Selection.TextToColumns , DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

    Next
```

Comment: So possibly a `.usedrange.columns.count`?  Then loop through columns, if column has used rows > X then `.texttocolumns`?

Comment: Do you want to find the last (bottom-most) non-empty cell in the last (right-most) non-empty column or something else? Note, there might be data in rows below in the columns before. In your case there might be data in cell `B4` when you might want to get cell `C4` although it is empty.

Comment: If you could explain where your data to be `TextToColumn-ed` is, and where you want to put the result e.g my data is in `A1:A5` , I want to put it into column `C`, but I don't want to overwrite data in e.g. `C3`, I want to start writing from `C4`...

Comment: @VBasic2008 I want indeed the last (right most) non empty cell, so in the third picture `C3`. Maybe there is in my code to splits the data (I'm not really able to understand all the code), but I want to format the numbers from text to numbers.